# Sentry-android self signed SSL certificate (SSLPeerUnverifiedException)

Tags: android, sentry

With Sentry Android SDK (`io.sentry:sentry-android:5.0.1`) - is there any way to pass custom HostnameVerifier or SHA-256/SHA-1 of SSL cert to authorize the usage of self-signed certs?

Currently I'm getting:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname xxxx not verified:
certificate: sha1/xxxx
DN: CN=xxxx
subjectAltNames: []
```

I already passed SHA-256 for that domain in my networkSecurityConfig XML file however it seems like it doesn't take that into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set one in through the options:

https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/blob/1f704cb3e630cb753ce0ac3390b6da5377c9e6ea/sentry/src/main/java/io/sentry/SentryOptions.java#L1193-L1195

```
SentryAndroid.init(o -> {
  o.setHostnameVerifier(...);
  o.setDsn(...);
  // other options
});
```

Note that if you're going to initialize programatically as I suggest above, you shouldn't add the configuration via the `AndroidManifest.xml` `meta-data` anymore.

Docs about this are here:
https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/android/configuration/manual-init/

Comment: Thanks, totally missed that in the docs that I can provide there Hostname Verifier and I think I overlook that when looking in the lib code. Thanks.